# .NET client library for JSON API spec jsonapi.org (Note JSON API != JSON format)

Tags: .net, json-api, jsonapiframework

In my app I'm talking to a JSON API backend API, and I need to both:
- deserialize from JSON API documents 
- serialize to JSON API resource objects.

I'm aware of the list from http://jsonapi.org/implementations/#client-libraries-net, but there are only two. Hypermedia library doesn't have both of serialize\deserialize available for client. 
The JsonApiFramework library wants me to derive POCO classes from its IResource interface. I don't like that.

Do you know other client libraries which has both JSON API deserializer and serialize?

Answer (score 0):

Just a FYI, the `IResource` interface in `JsonApiFramework` has no properties or methods as it is a pure "marker" interface used for generic inferences when using the fluent builder style that exists in `JsonApiFramework`. Other libraries have used this technique as well including Microsoft, but if you do not like that aspect I understand. I am looking to remove this constraint in v2.0 so we shall see...